A play on the Screwy Pirates Question
I was working through the Green Book and came across the classical Screwy Pirates problem, and I went down a rabbit hole.
Problem: There are 5 pirates ranked in seniority from 1 to 5, 1 being the most senior. There are 100 gold to be distributed. What is the optimal distribution, given that pirates a) want to preserve their life and then b) want to maximize their gold. If other pirates do not agree with the proposed distribution, if there is a $\geq$50% vote in agreement, the initial pirate will be killed. This is trivially solved by backtracking and will be left as an exercise.
I saw on Puzzle-Exchange a modified problem where there were infinitely many rounds and allowed for collusion, and was wondering if there was a Nash Equilibrium. The original answer suggested that an even split of 20-20-20-20-20 would be optimal, but my intuition says that cannot be true. I had to make an assumption or else the problem was too loose to solve.

Assumption: If a voting pirate is indifferent in decision, they will make the vote that will decrease the wealth disparity across all other pirates. For example, assume there are 3 pirates, and pirate 3 has a choice to make; either he can vote for pirate 1 to have 100 coins, pirate 2 to have 0, and pirate 3 to have 0; or he can vote to have pirate 1 to have 99 coins, pirate 2 to have 1 coin, and pirate 3 to have 0, he will vote for option 2.

For the sake of simplicity, I will now notate pirate 1 as $P_1$, pirate 2 as $P_2$... to pirate n as $P_n$. Additionally, coins will just be simplified to an integer, so if 3 pirates equally divide 100 coins, they would each have 33.
My Progress:
At $N=2$ for pirates, the trivial solution is the correct solution, $P_1 = 100, P_2 = 0$.
At $N=3$, I have proved that $P_1 = 99$ and $P_3 = 1$ is optimal.
Proof
If $P_1$ is voted out, we have our base case, where $P_2$ receives all the coins. In this case, $P_3$ is at least indifferent if $P_1$ is alive or not. However, if $P_1$ provides an incentive to $P_3$, then $P_3$ is unilaterally deviating to voting in alignment with $P_3$.
What I'm struggling is at $N\geq4$, is there a closed form solution to prove first that a) there is at least a Nash, and b) what the Nash would be?
My gut tells me that given $n$ pirates and $c$ coins, the lower bound for the coins kept by the senior pirate is $\frac{2c}{n}$, as you only need to pay off $\frac{n}{2}$ pirates to stop them from defecting. Additionally, I believe that there is a possibility where the Nash is in a state where the first pirate gets more than $\frac{2c}{n}$ coins.

The original problem posted on PuzzlingExchange.
